# Camera follows car in andengine

Tags: android, camera, box2d, andengine

I'm making race game.I have created srpite image of car.And I attached it to carBody(box2d).I have big map.So how can camera follow the car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mCamera.setChaseEntity(carSprite);
```

Next time, try using a search engine before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Just do whatever you do to the car to the Camera as well, So if you tell the car to move forward tell the camera to also move forward. Then just put in some if statements to make sure the distance is kept between the objects if you are doing any other modifiers to the camera.

```
If CameraX-CarX > (The distance you want from the car) CameraX++
If CameraX-CarX < (The distance you want from the car) CameraX--
```